# Import template from Sitecore to JSS React application

Tags: jss

I understand the mecanism when you create component code-first and then you import it into Sitecore.
I try to understand one point, how can I import new component from Sitecore (Sitecore-first ?) to the JSS React application ?

**For example :**
In Sitecore I created a template named "Article". I also created a new item named "My article".
Then I want to display it in my React JSS application.

What steps I need to achieve in both Sitecore and application side to make if work ?
If it's explained in a documentation please share a link because I can't find that information.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, I would suggest using the JSS CLI to scaffold Sitecore-first components. Run `jss deploy component --help` to see the options.

Manual process to create a "Sitecore-first" JSS component:

- Create a new datasource template to store the component's data fields. This template can be anywhere under `/sitecore/templates` (optional if the component has no data fields, but most will)
- Create a new `Json Rendering` item under `/layout/renderings/[anywhere]` to register the component with Sitecore

  - Under `Component Name` enter the name of the component that will be returned by Layout Service. This is the *name of your frontend component*, for example in the React sample it is the `Map` key in the `componentFactory.js` file.
  - Set the `Datasource Template` to your template, if using a datasource template
  - Set the `Datasource Location` to where you'd like to store the datasource item instances (i.e. `/sitecore/content/MySite/Component Content/Stuff` or `./Page Components`)
- Add the rendering to a route item's layout using Experience Editor
- Implement the React component and register it with the JSS app

Note: When using connected mode, there is no need to define the component schema in disconnected mode (i.e. to use anything in `/data` or `/sitecore/definitions`). Sitecore owns that data in connected mode.

Comment: Thanks  for your answer, I was able to create my component through JSS CLI and view it in SiteCore. Could you just clarify what means "add the component to a route with Experience Editor" (or share a documentation link) ?

Comment: Adding the component isn't really JSS-specific; something along the lines of this: http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/the-experience-editor/ (create route or edit existing, insert your component - if it doesn't show up as an option, may need placeholder settings assigned)

Comment: Hi Kam, how we need to implement the step "Implement the React component and register it with the JSS app". I created  a JSON rendering(HelloWorld) in sitecore and scaffold the same name in jss app jss scaffold HelloWorld. While adding to the experiance editor I get an error as "JSS component is missing React Implementation".

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're operating in Connected Mode. If so, review documentation here:

https://jss.sitecore.net/#/layout-service?id=the-sitecore-layout-service

A sample request is structured like this:

```
/sitecore/api/layout/render/[config]?item=[path]&sc_lang=[language]&sc_apikey=[key]&tracking=[true|false]
```

Comment: Hi Jon, so if I understand well, I just need to create an "Article" definition in my React appplication that match the fields of my Sitecore Article template ? And then request throught Layout API ?